# Simplification of Boolean expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory

please excuse my lack of correct notation.

I have the following sets:

1. D
2. M
3. F
4. N

All possible intersections of these four sets exist

I would like to know the simplest way of calculating members who are in D AND M AND F but not N.

Comment: I don't think any simplification is possible here (unless you want a product of sums representation instead)

Comment: By "simplest way" what do you want? An expression in terms of (disjoint) unions of intersections? What is "simple" (as opposed to impossible) also depends on what information you're initially given about values of $D, M, F, N$ and their interactions with intersections, unions, etc.

Comment: First, this seems to me elementary set theory rather than boolean algebra. You actually wish to find $D \cap M \cap F \cap N^c$, where $N^c$ is the compliment of $N$. What exactly do you mean as calculating its members?

Comment: @Logician6 I'm a little unsure how to detail it as my formal maths is elementary. If each set was a sphere then all three spheres would sit intersecting each other on the base - with a sphere balanced on top intersecting the below three

Comment: Well I've done "elementary set theory" in my day. Seems like you want something in the form of $A \cup B=A+B-A \cap B$. When you introduce a lot of items, well drawn Venn Diagrams are key. And typically you are given initial values that more or less dictate the problem.